# Faceted search does not want to display when hooked, Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

​

Hi I have a custom module that has popup with a custom hook in it. When I try hooking for example search bar it displays it perfectly, but when I try to hook faceted search it just displays comment like this [image] (I am reffering to image). I have no idea what is going on and why, here is the template

```
<div id="pp_myModal" class="pp_modal">
      <div class="pp_modal-content">
        <span class="pp_close">&times;</span>
        <p>
{hook h="displayPopup"}
    </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is the registering of hook:

```
public function hookDisplayPopup()
{
    return "";
}
```

I am probably registering it incorectly, but I did not found any other way. I tried this:

```
$hook = new Hook();
$hook->name = 'displayAtSpecificPlace';
$hook->title = 'The name of your hook';
$hook->description = 'This is a custom hook!';
$hook->position = 1;
$hook->add(); // return true on success
```

in install method, but it was installing infinitely long.

Thank you for your answers

code is here: https://easyupload.io/ankyv8